# Conditional posts in WP_query for search

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, query, search, meta-query

I have a custom post type that im trying to limit results in search.

The CPT is a deal/coupon, with a start and end date for each of the deals.

What I'm trying to do is only show these posts in search:

1. For non-recurring events....Show posts where the end date is today or after todays today.

**OR**

2. For recurring events, limit it to show only events with an end date between today which does not exceed 7 days.

Each of these queries works perfectly on their own, but I cant combine them together...

```
function search_pre_get_posts( $query ) {

    if ( $query->is_search() && $query->is_main_query()   ) {  
        $recurring_count = am_get_recurring_count($post->ID);
        // Show non-recurring events with end date of today or after
        if ($recurring_count == 0){
            $currentdate =  date('Y-m-d');
            $query->set( 
                'meta_query',
                array(
                    'relation' => 'OR',
                    array(
                         'key' => 'am_enddate',
                         'compare' => '>=',
                         'value' => $currentdate,
                    ),
                    array(
                         'key' => 'am_enddate',
                         'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
                    )
                )
            );
            $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value' );
            $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
        } else {
           // Show recurring events with end date of today or after, that doesnt exceed 7 days.
            $currentdate =  date('Y-m-d');
            $enddate = strtotime(date('Y-m-d') . "+7 days");
            $enddate = date('Y-m-d',$enddate);
            $query->set( 
                'meta_query',
                array(
                    'relation' => 'OR',
                    array(
                         'key' => 'am_enddate',
                         'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
                    ),
                    array(
                        'relation' => 'AND',
                        array(
                             'key' => 'am_enddate',
                             'compare' => '>=',
                             'value' => $currentdate,
                        ),
                        array(
                             'key' => 'am_enddate',
                             'compare' => '<=',
                             'value' => $enddate,
                        )
                    )
                )
            );
            $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value' );
            $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'search_pre_get_posts' );
```

Comment: I think you need to assign param `type` under you meta query, use `DATE` or `DATETIME` as value.

Answer (score 0):

What about removing the if statement, and combining the queries into something like this:

```
'meta_query',
array(
'relation' => 'OR',
    array(
        array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
                array(
                    'key' => 'am_get_recurring_count',
                    'compare' => '=',
                    'value' => '0',
                ),
                array(
                    'relation' => 'OR',
                    array(
                         'key' => 'am_enddate',
                         'compare' => '>=',
                         'value' => $currentdate,
                    ),
                    array(
                         'key' => 'am_enddate',
                         'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
                        )
                )
        )
    )
    array(
        array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
                array(
                    'key' => 'am_get_recurring_count',
                    'compare' => '!=',
                    'value' => '0',
                ),
                array(
                    'relation' => 'OR',
                    array(
                         'key' => 'am_enddate',
                         'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
                    ),
                    array(
                        'relation' => 'AND',
                        array(
                             'key' => 'am_enddate',
                             'compare' => '>=',
                             'value' => $currentdate,
                        ),
                        array(
                             'key' => 'am_enddate',
                             'compare' => '<=',
                             'value' => $enddate,
                        )
                    )
                )
        )

   )

 )
```

Haven't had a chance to test this yet.  Please let me know if it works.

Comment: I tried it and it was searching but not displaying any results. No errors. I also verified the date ranges were correct. Heres a link to the updated code (and i commented out the previous code): https://gist.github.com/bransonwerner/c238bef15bd620eeeeded51907b389ad

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function search_pre_get_posts( $query ) {

    if ( $query->is_search() && $query->is_main_query()   ) {  
            $currentdate =  date('Y-m-d');
            $enddate = strtotime(date('Y-m-d') . "+7 days");
            $enddate = date('Y-m-d',$enddate);

            $query->set( 
                'meta_query',
                array(
                    'relation' => 'OR',
                    array(
                         'key' => 'am_enddate',
                         'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
                    ),
                    array(
                        'relation' => 'OR',
                        array(
                            'key' => 'am_enddate',
                            'compare' => '>=',
                            'value' => $currentdate,
                        ),
                        array(
                            'key' => 'am_recurrence_id',
                            'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
                        )
                    ),
                    array(
                        'relation' => 'AND',
                        array(
                             'key' => 'am_enddate',
                             'compare' => '>=',
                             'value' => $currentdate,
                        ),
                        array(
                             'key' => 'am_enddate',
                             'compare' => '<=',
                             'value' => $enddate,
                        ),
                        array(
                            'key' => 'am_recurrence_id',
                            'compare' => 'EXISTS',
                        )
                    )
                )
            );
            $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value' );
            $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'search_pre_get_posts' );
```